# How to display mathematical typesetting (MathJax, LaTeX, etc.) in Qt using PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, latex, pyqt5, mathjax

I am fairly new to Qt and PyQt5 and would like to display mathematical typesetting in a GUI window. Specifically, I would like it to be able to update dynamically. I can't seem to find any helpful information on how to do this with PyQt5.

I've thoroughly researched how to do this

One seemingly relevant answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466204/mathematical-equations-rendering-and-evaluation-with-python-and-qt-and-sympy), but no solution is given and it doesn't actually address the issue of showing the typeset math in a GUI.

Another seemingly relevant answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035251/displaying-latex-in-pyqt-pyside-qtablewidget), but uses PySide (and python 2.7) and gives an absurdly and unecessarily complicated and outdated answer.

Comment: [displaying-latex-in-pyqt-pyside-qtablewidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035251/displaying-latex-in-pyqt-pyside-qtablewidget)

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I don't see how either of those address the question I am asking. The first post doesn't have an accepted answer and doesn't give a relevant solution. The second answer is for a different version of Python, an outdated version of QT, and gives an absurdly and unnecessarily complicated solution.

Comment: Yeah. But beside _saying_ "I've thoroughly researched how to do this" you did not show any of your search results. So I thought I spend 1 minute of googling and give you some tips to look at. The first question has no _accepted_ answer - but an answer you can follow up upon. The 2.7  solution could be adapted to use 3.x as well...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out how to do this in a manner that is quite easy and simple. The example given below requires internet connectivity to access the MathJax JS module.

1. First, import **QApplication** and **QWebEngineView**.

   ```
   import sys
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
   from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
   ```
2. Then, write a multi-line string containing HTML code. The code should import the MathJax javascript module. Then, write your mathematical equation...

   ```
   pageSource = """
                <html><head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">                     
                </script></head>
                <body>
                <p><mathjax style="font-size:2.3em">$$u = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(awesome)\cdot du$$</mathjax></p>
                </body></html>
                """
   ```
3. Finally, instantiate a QApplication, instantiate a QWebEngineView, and set the WebEngineView to show your newly written HTML code:

   ```
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   webView = QWebEngineView()
   webView.setHtml(pageSource)
   ```
4. Don't forget to call show on your WebEngineView.

   ```
   webView.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

*If you want to create an app that does not require internet connectivity to run the MathJax JS file, simply copy the JS module and save it as a string in your code.*