# Qt5 display mathematical formulas

Tags: qt, qt5

Is there a way to display mathematical formulas with `Qt5`?
I would need a way to display formulas like the below one:

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760843/how-to-display-mathematical-typesetting-mathjax-latex-etc-in-qt-using-pyqt5).

Answer (score -1):

I found this code for you:

.h

```
#ifndef FORMULAWIDGET_H
#define FORMULAWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class FormulaItem
{
public:
    explicit FormulaItem(QString value) : m_value(value){}

    static const QString REGULAR_EXPRESSION; 
    QPoint draw(const QPoint& pos, QPainter& p) const;

private:
    QString m_value;
};

class FormulaWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    using BaseClass = QWidget;
public:
    explicit FormulaWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void setFormula(const QString& formula);

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;

private:
    QList<FormulaItem> m_items;
};

#endif // FORMULAWIDGET_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "FormulaWidget.h"
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOption>


const QString FormulaItem::REGULAR_EXPRESSION = "sqrt\\((?<value>\\d+)\\)";

QPoint FormulaItem::draw(const QPoint& pos, QPainter& p) const
{
    int valueWidth = p.fontMetrics().width(m_value);
    int valueHeight = p.fontMetrics().height();

    p.drawLine(pos.x(), 4 + valueHeight / 2, pos.x() + 5, 4 + valueHeight);
    p.drawLine(pos.x() + 5, 4 + valueHeight, pos.x() + 10, pos.y() + 1);
    p.drawLine(pos.x() + 10, pos.y() + 1, pos.x() + 14 + valueWidth, pos.y() + 1);

    p.drawText(QRect(pos.x() + 12, pos.y() + 4, pos.x() + 12 + valueWidth, pos.y() + 4 + valueHeight), m_value);
    return QPoint(pos.x() + valueWidth + 20, pos.y());
}

FormulaWidget::FormulaWidget(QWidget* parent) :
    BaseClass(parent)
{
    QPalette pal = palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setPalette(pal);
}

void FormulaWidget::setFormula(const QString& formula)
{
    m_items.clear();

    QRegularExpression sqrt_value(FormulaItem::REGULAR_EXPRESSION);
    QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = sqrt_value.globalMatch(formula);

    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
        if (match.hasMatch())
        {
            m_items.append(FormulaItem(match.captured("value")));
        }
    }

    update();
}

void FormulaWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.setPen(Qt::black);

    QPoint formulaPos(2, 2);

    for (const FormulaItem& item : m_items)
    {
        formulaPos = item.draw(formulaPos, p);
    }
}
```

Example here: https://evileg.com/en/post/339/

Comment: But it is only for square root, come on! What about other formulas?