# PyQt5: Reference local copy of Mathjax in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mathjax, qwebengineview

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760843/how-to-display-mathematical-typesetting-mathjax-latex-etc-in-qt-using-pyqt5) and [the mathjax 3 documentation](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax#hosting-your-own-copy-of-the-mathjax-components), I am trying to render a simple html with Mathjax content in PyQt5 using a local copy of the mathjax repo.
The main directory contains the notebook from which the following code is executed, a "mathjax" folder containing the content of the repo (especially the es5 folder). Notice that I tried with 2 paths to the js (comment toward the top) :

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import os

# <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/mocquin/.../mathjax/es5/tex-chtml-full.js">                     

pageSource = """
             <html><head>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="./mathjax/es5/tex-chtml-full.js">                     
             </script></head>
             <body>
             <p><mathjax style="font-size:2.3em">$$u = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(awesome)\cdot du$$</mathjax></p>
             </body></html>
             """

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
webView = QWebEngineView()
webView.setHtml(pageSource, baseUrl=QUrl(os.path.abspath('')))

webView.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But this only renders the content without the "latex parsing" [image]

What am I missing so that the mathjax is indeed linked to the html ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that you aren't using the correct format for the src path and base url. The src path must be a plain relative path, and the base url should be a backslash-terminated absolute path to the directory containing the mathjax directory.

Assuming the mathjax directory is in *the same directory as the python script*, the following should work correctly (at least, it does for me):

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

pageSource = """
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="mathjax/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p><mathjax style="font-size:2.3em">$$u = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(awesome)\cdot du$$</mathjax></p>
</body></html>
"""

baseurl = QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/')

print(f'BASEURL: {baseurl.toString()!r}') # BASEURL: 'file:///home/tmp/test/'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
webView = QWebEngineView()
webView.setHtml(pageSource, baseUrl=baseurl)
webView.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Works fine thanks ! I knew the problem were the paths..