# Enforce custom ordering on Sympy print

Tags: python, sympy

`SymPy` does a wonderful work keeping track of all the operations I do to my symbolic expressions. But a the moment of printing the result for latex output I would like to enforce a certain ordering of the term. This is just for convention, and unfortunately that convention is not alphabetical on the symbol name(as reasonably `sympy` does)

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
U,tp, z, d = sp.symbols('U t_\perp z d')
# do many operations with those symbols
# the final expression is:

z+tp**2+U+U/(z-3*tp)+d
```

My problem is that `SymPy` presents the expression ordered as

```
U + U/(-3*t_\perp + z) + d + t_\perp**2 + z
```

But this ordering is not the convention in my field. For us `z` has to be the leftmost expression, then `tp`, then `U` even if it is capitalized, `d` is the most irrelevant and is put at the right. All this variables hold a particular meaning and that is the reason we write them in such order, and the reason in the code variables are named in such way.

I don't want to rename `z` to `a` and as suggested in [Prevent Sympy from rearranging the equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624511/prevent-sympy-from-rearranging-the-equation) and then at the moment of printing transform that `a` into `z`. In [Force SymPy to keep the order of terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314035/python-sympy-force-sympy-to-keep-order?noredirect=1&lq=1) there is a hint I can write a sorting function but I could not find documentation about it.

Answer (score 5):

If you can put the terms in the order you want then setting the `order` flag for the Latex printer to 'none' will print them in that order.

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> sp.init_printing()
>>> U,tp, z, d = sp.symbols('U t_\perp z d')
>>> eq=z+tp**2+U+U/(z-3*tp)+d
```

Here we put them in order (knowing the power of `tp` is 2) and rebuild as an Add with `evaluate=False` to keep the order unchanged

```
>>> p = Add(*[eq.coeff(i)*i for i in (z, U, tp**2, d)],evaluate=False)
```

And now we print that expression with a printer instance with `order='none'`:

```
>>> from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
>>> s=LatexPrinter(dict(order='none'))
>>> s._print_Add(p)
z + U \left(1 + \frac{1}{z - 3 t_\perp}\right) + t_\perp^{2} + d
```