# Printing a polynomial so that the powers of x or s are in ascending or descending order

Tags: python, sympy

I can't find a method or function that will order the powers of the polynomial terms in either ascending or descending order.
I am using sympy to calculate some transfer functions using Laplace transforms.

I have found only collect() helps combine powers of s but it can't print the powers of s in ascending or descending order.
I see print outs like this

```
CLTF(s)=(K*Kd*ω**2*s + K*Kp*ω**2)/(K*Kp*ω**2 + 2*ζ*ω*s**2 + s**3 + s*(K*Kd*ω**2 + ω**2))
```

The powers of s are not in the right order in the denominator

```
from math import pi
from sympy import symbols, init_printing, ratsimp, fraction, pprint, collect
from sympy.solvers import solve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
init_printing()
s, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4 = symbols('s, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4')
Ki, Kp, Kd, K2 = symbols('Ki, Kp, Kd, K2')
K, nf, df = symbols('K, nf, df')
cltf, Ga, Gc, num, den = symbols('cltf, Ga, Gc, num, den')

Gc = Kp+Kd*s                                 # controller transfer function
Ga = 5/(s*(s**2+4*s+5))                 # open loop transfer function
Ga = 5/(s*(s**2+2*s+5))                 # open loop transfer function
Ga = K*nf**2/(s*(s**2+2*df*nf*s+nf**2))
# calculate the symbolic equation for  the closed loop transfer function
cltf = collect(ratsimp((Gc*Ga)/(1+Gc*Ga)),s)
print("\n\nClosed Loop Transfer Function = ")
pprint(cltf)
(num, den) = fraction(cltf)             # separate into numerator and denominator
print("\n\nCharacteristic Equation = ")
pprint(collect(den,s))
zeros = solve(num,s)                    # find the symbolic zeros
roots = solve(den,s)                    # find the symbolic roots
num_str=str(num)
num_str0 = num_str.replace("nf",u"\u03C9")
den_str=str(collect(den,s))
den_str0 = den_str.replace("nf",u"\u03C9")
den_str1 = den_str0.replace("df",u"\u03B6")
print("\n\nCLTF(s)=({})/({})".format(num_str0,den_str1))
```

There are no error messages.  I simply do not get the print out I want.
The powers of s are not in any order.
Also there is no horner function that would print a third order polynomial like this

```
((d*x+c)*x+b)*x+a instead of a+b*x+c*x**2+d*x**3
```

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.coeffs ?

Comment: I saw that before.  coeffs only prints the coefficients,  it does no print the whole polynomial in lex or reverse lex order.  I also hoped the init_printing() function would control the order.  init_printing has a order='lex' or order='old' or order ='grevlex' would do the trick.  The order option in init_printing do not seem to work right.

Comment: have you tried without ratsimp?

Comment: I tried without ratsimp.  There was no simplification of the closed loop transfer function.  It was worse.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615872/how-to-modify-sympys-printing-order

Comment: Links mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414547/enforce-custom-ordering-on-sympy-print?rq=1 ?