# How to pass args to sympy.lambdify

Tags: python, sympy

This is a more precise version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183406/sympy-calculation-of-division?noredirect=1#comment129279138_73183406) where the comments said my minimal reproducible code was too minimal, so with more information:

I want to evaluate an `Expression` without having to pass the symbols along separately. My current workaround is this:

```
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify


def evaluate_expr(expr):
    lambdified = lambdify(tuple(expr.free_symbols), expr)
    return lambdified(*[i.value for i in expr.free_symbols])


class symbol_x(Symbol):
    def __new__(cls, symbol, value):
        obj = Symbol.__new__(cls, symbol)
        obj.value = value
        return obj

x = symbol_x('x', 2)
y = symbol_x('y', 3)

value = evaluate_expr(x / y)
print(value)
```

This works. My problem is that `expr.free_symbols` is a `set` (which doesn't maintain order), so casting it to a `tuple` might create unexpected bugs. What would be the correct way of evaluating this expression?

Comment: The fact that you have attached a numerical value to each of your symbols is a crucial piece of information that was missing from your previous question. There isn't any benefit in using `lambdify` if you use it this way (only calling the function once). It would be better to just use `subs` or `evalf` with the `subs` argument.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin the problem is that the value of x and y might change later down the road... But thanks, I'll have a look at it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Defining `args=tuple(expr.free_symbols)` and using `args` in both lines of `evaluate` will (doubly) ensure the order is the same.

Comment: If the value of `x` and `y` might change then I still don't think that the question as posed above really represents the problem you are trying to solve. I still don't understand what you are trying to do: in the example above you could just use `x=2` and `y=3` and not bother with the strange symbol that has a number attached (the point of symbols is that they are supposed to represent *unknown* values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the free symbols according to some reproducible logic, like sorting by name:

```
def evaluate_expr(expr):
    fs = sorted(expr.free_symbols, key=lambda t: t.name)
    lambdified = lambdify(fs, expr)
    return lambdified(*[i.value for i in fs])
```

Edit for explanation:

The problem is that `expr.free_symbols` returns a set. `lambdify` requires a list. In Python, the conversion from a set to a list is non-deterministic. For example, say you have a set `{a, b}`. When you convert it to a list you can either have `[a, b]` or `[b, a]`.

To fix this behavior, we can use `sorted` to sort the free symbols alphabetically.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how sorting the symbols to a logic I understand will effect `sympy`s functionality. Could you elaborate on how this prevents bugs from occurring?

Comment: added explanation on the answer.

Comment: I must be overlooking something. I understand making it sorted ensures it's deterministic, but how does it being deterministic prevent bugs compared to the non sorted list input?

Comment: In your original code, you used `tuple(expr.free_symbols)` inside `lambdify` and then you executed your function with `lambdified(*[i.value for i in expr.free_symbols])`. The problem is that in the last command, `expr.free_symbols` might have a different order in comparison to `tuple(expr.free_symbols)` (remember, non-deterministic conversion). So, if your function has the form `lambdified(x, y)`, with the last command it is possible to execute it with `lambdified(y, x)`, which will create the wrong result. With sorted arguments, that problem goes away! No bugs.

Comment: ahhh so I could do `args = tuple(expr.free_symbols)` and pass `args` both times. The order doesn't matter as long as it's the same.