# How can I arrange the output of sympy.latex when the input is an expression made of constants?

Tags: python, latex, sympy

sympy.latex arranges the terms of an equation in ascending order:

[image: this]

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667919/7661420) which provides a way to arrange the output of sympy.latex if you are using symbols.

Is there a way to arrange an expression of constants, so that the output of sympy.latex is something like this?

[image: this].